# Accordion made in react with strange behavior toggling tabs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, accordion

I'm making an accordion in react, it's almost done except for **one** thing. The behavior after click in another tab that is supposed to close the previous tab (only one tab is allowed) AND scroll top to 0 of the viewport.

The issue is, when I click the first time in tabs the they behave correctly, but when I click in any tab AFTER this one they open and scroll top but after they "move up" the dom probably to the offset difference of the last tab. I've tried many things and the best of I got was a scrollToTop with some settimeout but they scroll top the whole offset of the previous tab, instead of just move the rest of the viewport to the top.

In summary: 
1- The first tab scroll Top correctly
2- The second tab close the first correctly, scroll top but they "move" instead of expand.

In summary: 
1- The first tab scroll Top correctly
2- The second tab close the first correctly, scroll top but they "move" instead of expand.

**Correct Behavior:** 
https://media.giphy.com/media/l0Iy9aw7hhVkiZRvO/giphy.gif

**Wrong Behavior:** https://media.giphy.com/media/3o7bu1ZEGPexohh6Sc/giphy.gif

I created a [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/TlpwhGFROY9pioCWU2mC?p=preview) trying to accomplish a MCVE but wihtout success, but theres's my code.

The 2 major scripts is **Materias.js** and **MateriaExpanded.js**

I already inspected that my error are when i generate which element are open ( Like I said only one is allowed).
in **Materias.js**

```
  ownToggle(id, ref, e) {
    const self = this.state.elementsOpen[id];
    const hash = this.generateElementsOpen(this.props.items, id);
    if (!self) {
      hash[id] = true;
    }
    this.setState({
      elementsOpen: hash, // bug
    });

  }
```

My snippet in **MateriaExpanded.js**

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import FontAwesome from 'react-fontawesome';
import $ from 'jquery';
import moment from 'moment';
import Content from './Content.js';
import Footer from './Footer.js';
import './style.css';

class MateriaExpanded extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.renderSocialNetworks = this.renderSocialNetworks.bind(this);
    this.childToggle = this.childToggle.bind(this);
    this.renderTimeDiff = this.renderTimeDiff.bind(this);
    this.className = this.className.bind(this);
    this.disableThumbor = this.disableThumbor.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.materiasContainers(this.containerRef);
  }
  childToggle(itemId, ref, e) {
    this.props.calcViewPort(itemId, ref, false);
    setTimeout(() => { this.props.ownToggle(itemId, ref, e) }, 400);
  }
  className() {
    if (this.props.isOpen && this.props.item.img_url.length < 1) {
      return 'withoutImg containerImageFluid';
    }
    if (this.props.isOpen && this.props.item.img_url.length > 0) {
      return 'containerImageFluid';
    }
    if (!this.props.isOpen && this.props.item.img_url.length < 1) {
      return 'containerImageSimple withoutImg';
    }
    if (!this.props.isOpen && this.props.item.img_url.length > 0) {
      return 'containerImageSimple';
    }
    return;
  }
  disableThumbor() {
    const newUrl = this.props.item.img_url.split('http://');

    const newUrlWithoutThumbor = newUrl[newUrl.length - 1];

    return `url(http://${newUrlWithoutThumborcontent})no-repeat top center`;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className={this.props.isOpen ? 'opened' : 'closed'}
        ref={(containerRef) => { this.containerRef = containerRef; }}
      >
        <div 
          onClick={(e) => this.childToggle(this.props.item.id, this.containerRef, e)}
          className={this.className()}
          style={{
            background: this.disableThumbor(),
            transitionTimingFunction: 'cubic-bezier(0.9, 0.54, 0.33, 0.85)',
            transitionDuration: '1.1s',
            transform: 'translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)',
            backgroundSize: 'cover',
          }}
        >
          { this.props.item.is_video ?
            (
              <FontAwesome
                className={style.videoStyle}
                name="play"
              />
            ) : null
          }
        </div>
        <div className={style.containerContent}>
          <div>
            <div onClick={(e) => this.childToggle(this.props.item.id, this.containerRef, e)}>
              <div className={style.resume}>
                <span className={this.props.isOpen ? 'descriptionOpened' : 'description'}>{this.props.item.category}</span>
                <span className={style.descriptionTime}>TIME</span>
              </div>
              <h1 className={this.props.isOpen ? 'materiaOpen' : 'title'}>{this.props.item.title} </h1>
              <h3 className='preview'>{this.props.item.subtitle}</h3>
              <div className={style.socialNetwork}> social networks </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className={this.props.isOpen ? 'containerMateria' : 'containerHide'}>
            <HeaderComponent
              title={this.props.item.title}
              id={this.props.item.id}
              subtitle={this.props.item.subtitle}
              category={this.props.item.categoria}
            />
            <Content content={this.props.item.content.body} time={this.renderTimeDiff()} />
            <Footer />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MateriaExpanded;

MateriaExpanded.propTypes = {
  item: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  items: PropTypes.func,
  changeHeaderExpanded: PropTypes.func,
  toggle: PropTypes.func,
  materiasContainers: PropTypes.func,
  materiaClick: PropTypes.func,
  isOpen: PropTypes.bool,
  ownToggle: PropTypes.func,
  calcViewPort: PropTypes.func,
};
```

**EDIT 1**: I've created a temp repo on github to help people inspect my bug
https://github.com/yuripramos/temp-multicontent